# Supremum and infimum of the set

Tags: analysis

Suppose that there is a set $E := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x = 1 + (-1)^{n}n^{-1}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I aim to find the supremum and infimum of the set, while proving that they are indeed supremum and infimum of the set. Finding infimum and proving it is not so hard to me, but for supremum, it's a little confusing. I can't help but write "it's obvious" or such phrases I wish I hadn't used.

Any suggestions? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For even $n$, $1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = 1 + 1/n$, and this decreases as $n$ increases.

For odd $n$, $1+ \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = 1 - 1/n$, and this increases as $n$ increases.

So, the smallest is when $n=1$ which gives $x=0$, and the largest is when $n=2$ which gives you $3/2$. Now, you can use the technical definition of supremum and infimum if you want.